# How to I initialised a dictionary in swift4 with key as String and Value as 2D array?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Currently, I have a 2D array already filled with numbers. 
I would like to initialise a dictionary with the value as 2D array.

This is my grid:

```
var grid: [[String]] = [[String]](repeating: [String](repeating : "_" , count: 10), count: 10)
```

This is my dictionary:

```
var membersGrid = [String: [[String]]]()
```

When I do this, I keep getting an error:

```
membersGrid[InstanceDAO.team_id]?.append(grid)
```

> Cannot convert value of type '[[String]]' to expected argument type '[String]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do an assignment

```
membersGrid[InstanceDAO.team_id] = grid
```